# Adding double quotes with white spaces words in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string in below format.

```
Banking Sector AND Lorem Ispum Dummy text AND Partner OR Agri Business NOT Corporate Finance
```

I need to convert this query into below format using PHP.

```
"Banking Sector" AND "Lorem Ispum Dummy text" AND "Partner" OR "Agri Business" NOT "Corporate Finance"
```

I need to add double quotes for words in between the AND/OR/NOT operators. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) and also at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), we are here to help you, not write code for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Your string don't start and don't terminate with (AND/OR/NOT) You can use this:

```
$output = str_replace(array(" AND "," OR "," NOT "),array('" AND "','" OR "','" NOT "'),$input);
$output ='"'.trim($output).'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` and `backreferences`. Something like this:

```
preg_replace("(.+)\s(AND|OR|NOT)\s(.+)", "\"$1\"\s$2\s\"$3\"")
```

**disclaimer**: un-tested